# Does INVOKESTATIC operation reverse stack order?

Tags: java, bytecode

I was studying java byte-code, when i noticed that the simple expression Math.max(0,1) gets turned into the following byte-code instructions.

```
ICONST_0, 
ICONST_1, 
INVOKESTATIC(java/lang/Math.max)
```

My question is if java uses a last in first out stack, that means that the 1 would now be in front of the 0 on the stack, which means the vm must then reverse the order of the items on the stack when it calls the max instruction to get the 0 before the 1.  However in the specification, it says noting about this, is my hypothesis correct.

Comment: Why would it matter, even if it weren't already how things are done?  Math.max(0, 1) == Math.max(1, 0).  Methinks you need a better example.

Comment: @cHao I disagree. The same bytecode would be generated for any method regardless if it was commutative or not.

Comment: @Jeffrey: Thing is, it doesn't matter here.  A bit.  A too-smart compiler could even rearrange the two args just cause it felt like it, and it wouldn't change a thing.  An example where the order actually matters would be more useful.

Comment: @cHao If you could find a compiler that can determine if a method is commutative or not, I would be impressed.

Comment: @Jeffrey: `Math` is part of the libraries that come with Java.  There's nothing that needs determining.  Either the function acts as defined, or it's not Java.

Comment: @cHao The compiler doesn't understand what each individual method does. It has no way of knowing that the order of the arguments does not matter for a particular method, and even if it did, I can't see the benefit of being able to arbitrarily reorder arguments on the stack.

Comment: Keep in mind that after the invoke operands are pushed onto the stack they are conceptually addressed as an array, with the first-pushed value being in element zero.  They are not "popped" on the callee side, but instead effectively appear as local variables.

Comment: @cHao It would be entirely futile for a compiler to behave as you describe, and compiler writers aren't any more disposed to wasting their time than anybody else. Your point continues to escape me, as does the point of the four words after 'Math.max()'.

Comment: @EJP: My point is that right now, no matter how wacky an idea it seems to be, there's room to say "the args got reversed because the compiler thought it'd be a better idea".  Whereas with a non-commutative operation, which would produce a different, clearly incorrect result...when the args are pushed "backwards", and the result is correct, that pretty much settles it.

Comment: @cHao Your point still escapes me. Compilers don't do that; this compiler didn't do that; the arguments *weren't* reversed in the first place. The only thing that makes sense in your whole pointless discussion is your original observation that it doesn't actually make any difference ... in this specific case.

Comment: @EJP: Erm...optimizing compilers *do* do stuff at least resembling that, on a regular basis.  But that's beside the point.  If you're investigating what you consider odd behavior, and you want to learn anything at all from testing it, you should be trying to highlight the difference between what you think it should be, what it *should* be, and what it is, and eliminates other factors.  A test where every arrangement, correct or incorrect, optimized or not, backwards or forwards -- no matter how or why it is chosen -- yields the same result...is useless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The argument stack is just an abstraction. When an operation takes n arguments, the top n arguments are taken off the stack and used from bottom to top, as you have observed. This applies not just for invokestatic, but for every single bytecode instruction.

For example, the following sequence

iconst_0
iconst_1
iconst_2
isub

Pushes 0,1, and 2 onto the stack. The isub instruction pops off the top two values, 1, and 2 and uses them from bottom to top so the result is 1-2 = -1. Therefore, the end result is a stack containing 0, -1.

If you're interested in details like this, you should try reading the JVM specification.

Answer (score 1):

> if java uses a last in first out stack

There's another kind?

> which means the vm must then reverse the order of the items on the stack when it calls the max instruction to get the 0 before the 1

No it doesn't. The zero is already 'before' the one. Arguments to *any* method are pushed in the order they occur in the source text, as indeed are local variable declarations. I don't know why you think any reversal is required. It isn't.

Comment: but wouldnt iconst_1 then push 1 onto the top of the stack after 0 is already pushed on the stack

Comment: Of course it does. So? You seem to have some major misconception about what happens inside the called method. I suggest you have a look at the byte code for Math.max() to clear that up.